# why ampl makes a syntax error param 1<<<< 12000?

Tags: syntax, parameters, syntax-error, ampl

I have a permanent ampl syntax error when I define matrix parameters. Here is how I defined my parameters : 
D is a vector of 7 integers !

#

> data; reset;
>
> param NP:=7; param NT:=4;
>
> param D:= 
>   1 12000 2 32000 3 25000 4 36000  5 25000 6 30000 7 18000 ;

So, I get the syntax error :

> prod_elec.dat, line 8 (offset 53):    syntax error context:  1  >>>
>   12000 <<<

Please help me, I have no idea how to solve that, I followed the definitions of the book that used to work for me too..

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: https://ampl.com/resources/the-ampl-book/chapter-downloads/

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you mean for D to be an indexed parameter, but the code you posted doesn't declare it as being indexed. Even if there was a previous model statement which did declare it as indexed, that would be deleted by your `reset` statement. So AMPL expects a single value, and when it sees a second value (here 12000) it gives an error.

Something like this should work:

```
reset;
model;
param NP;
param NT;
param D{1..NP};
data; 
param NP:=7; param NT:=4;
param D:= 1 12000 2 32000 3 25000 4 36000 5 25000 6 30000 7 18000 ;
```